# How do you embed a C# Form into HTML?

Tags: c#, html, forms, embed

I've used Visual Studio Express to create a C# Form but I want to embed it in my website. I'm quite new to C# and Html and I would like to know how to embed a C# Form in Html. Just to let you know I am using Weebly and there is a custom Html element that i wish to place a C# Form in.

Comment: When you say `form`, are you talking about Windows Forms? Or are you talking about Web Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer can [host .NET controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301932.aspx), but it is not recommended any more - this feature has been deprecated by Microsoft, replaced by Silverlight.  I'm not sure what the current outlook is on the future of Silverlight.